# How to subtract two time columns with timedelta (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I'm trying for hours to do a subtraction between this two time columns so I can see how long did it take to the other action happen:

```
In[1]:aumento_data_separada 
Out[1]: Response_Time      Request_Time(when the client do a request)   
 0   00:56:58.612000    00:46:34.347000
 1   12:00:41.069000    12:00:32.603000
 2   18:05:02.776000    16:39:42.682000
 3   19:27:11.997000    17:33:05.589000 
...
```

This dataframe has more 392560 rows like these above. I'd like to do the operation in all of them. and creat a new column with the result.
I tried reading the docs from timedelta, but I didn't understand it at all. 
I did this -> `type(aumento_data_separada['Response_Time'].iloc[0])` and `type(aumento_data_separada['Request_Time'].iloc[0])` to see the type and it returned me a  `datetime.time`. I found out that I can't do operations within them because of the type. So I tried to convert them separately: `pd.to_datetime(aumento_data_separada['Request_Time'])` but it returns me the following error-> `object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()`.

Here is the 1st error message and the code I tried -> `aumento_data_separada.Response_Time - aumento_data_separada.Request_Time` -
returning `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: Can you please show your attempt?

Comment: I tried things that I'm sure are completely wrong.
 `dif =aumento_data_separada[ 'Response_Time'] - datetime.timedelta(1)
delta = dif - aumento_data_separada[ 'Request_Time']
a = datetime.timedelta(aumento_data_separada['response_at'])
`

Comment: Sabrina, your question should include your code attempt, so that people trying to answer it have something to fix. At the moment, your question just looks like an attempt to get free consulting services from the community.  [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41107479/edit), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ghoti! I'm new here and in programming haha so I'm still getting used to the way things work, and your feedback about my question was very important, so I don't make the same mistake again! I edited it, hope it's better :)

Answer (score 3):

convert the columns to `pd.Timedelta` with `pd.to_timedelta`

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_timedelta)

df.Response_Time - df.Request_Time

0   00:10:24.265000
1   00:00:08.466000
2   01:25:20.094000
3   01:54:06.408000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I tried it but it gave me the following error:
`("Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <type 'datetime.time'>", u'occurred at index Response_Time')
`

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to piRSquared's answer, but for some reason this is faster when I test the two methods side-by-side. Not sure why that is.

```
df['Time_Diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Response_Time) - pd.to_datetime(df.Request_Time)
```

Comment: I got this error -> `object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()
`